# Is RCW(Runtime Callable Wrapper) the only way of calling an unmanaged com object in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, com

I'm working on a project where I need to call an unmanaged COM object in C#.net project. In this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice), I have found that in order to call a COM object in .net, one needs to have a RC Wrapper on that object. So, I'm just curious to know if this is the only way to proceed?? or Do we have any other way of calling a COM object in .NET?

Comment: If you can update to C# 4.0 (As I guess that you are still in C# 3.0) to gain dynamic : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714583.aspx

Comment: That article you linked is complete nonsense, it doesn't demonstrate any COM code.  A common problem with that web site, no meaningful review.  An RCW is an implementation detail, you never create one explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS allows you to simply add a reference to your COM DLL. It is just a tab in your "Add Reference" dialog. The process is quite seamless for most scenarios. It *automatically generates* a complete RCW for you. You do not need to write any manual code.

See [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

---

If you need more control, another way is to create a C++/CLI or Managed C++ class which manages and invokes your COM class. This Managed C++ class can be invoked in turn by your C# code. You are essentially creating a "manual" wrapper around your COM code. C++/CLI is a hybrid language combining elements of both managed .NET and unmanaged C++ code.

This article explains the basics: [Quick C++/CLI - Learn C++/CLI in less than 10 minutes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes). You will need to adapt it to add the usual lifecycle management code for COM classes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just going with creating a new Managed C++ class.